# How can I get an ObjectSet<T> with EF Code First CTP5 (for a generic repository?)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, repository-pattern, code-first

For Code First CTP 3 and 4 I had a generic repository pattern implemented by implementing a method in my `DbContext` that had `return this.ObjectContext.CreateObjectSet<T>`.  This allowed me to create an object set for any type I needed, which I can then use Linq to code against.

Last night I upgraded to CTP5 and it seems like they have changed a lot of how `DbContext` was implemented.  One aspect is there is no longer an `ObjectContext` property in the `DbContext` class.  As far as I can tell, there is no method to create an `ObjectSet<T>` or any other dataset that I can use to access on demand generically that will be tied to the data context.

I then had the idea to create a `DbSet<T>` in the method instead, as that could allow me to perform linq-to-entities operations on it.  This doesn't work either though, as there are no constructors for `DbSet<T>` (or so the compiler tells me) and I have no way to tie it to the existing instance of my data context.

Does anyone have any idea how to implement a generic repository with Code First CTP5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have my repositories return `IQueryable<T>`.  Both `ObjectSet<T>` and `DbSet<T>` implement that interface.  To obtain a `DbSet<T>` with code-first, either pull the property off of the context class you've created, or the base class that your context classes uses has a method called `Set<T>()` which will return the `DbSet<T>`.

HTH

Comment: Aha, I missed the `Set<T>()` method.  Thanks!